# Docker Transparent Network and port mapping

Tags: windows, docker, docker-for-windows

I am trying to get a WCF application running in a docker windows container.

I have played around with the different types of networking for a docker windows container.  Seems there are two main options NAT and Transparent.

NAT is the default, and easily supports the `-p 8080:80` type syntax to map a port.  However, NAT blocks me from accessing anything outside the computer.  (Meaning I cannot connect to other network resources.)

Transparent works great for accessing my network resources.  But when I try to run it with `-p 8080:80` it gives the following error:

```
failed to create endpoint distracted_gates on network basic: hnsCall failed in Win32: 
Port mapping is not supported on the given network. (0x803b0016).
```

Seems "Port mapping is not supported" on Transparent networks.

So, this leads to my question:

**How do I specify a port to connect to my windows service using a Transparent network?**  (or is there a better way that I have not understood.)

Note: In case it is relevant, here is my docker run command (that gives the above error message):

```
docker run --network myTransparentNetwork --security-opt "credentialspec=file://mygMSA.json" -d -p 8080:80 myContainerImage:myTag
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to map ports in a bridge (linux) or transparent (windows) networks. The requirement in this scenario is to make the use of the `EXPOSE` keyword within your Dockerfile.

The `EXPOSE` keyword in most of the scenarios (where NAT is used) are more useful for documentation purposes once you still have to map your `-p hostPort:containerPort`.

See below an example of the `EXPOSE` keyword in the Dockerfile:

```
#document ports that are mandatory
EXPOSE 8080 8090 9000
```